# Mostrar número de notificações na barra de título

Tags: novo-recurso

O Stack costuma mostrar no número de novas perguntas `(2)` quando na página principal:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém eu acho que seria muito mais útil mostrar o número de notificações, não acham?

---

### Update

Postado no Metão!: [Show the number of notifications in the page title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233994/number-of-notifications-in-the-title-bar)

Comment: Achei legal a idéia ...

Comment: -1 Prefiro as perguntas

Comment: @Andrey talvez fosse o caso de postar isso no Metão, já que não vejo a menor chance de o SOPT ter um comportamento diferente do restando do SE inteiro. Ou então pode esperar um pouco para amadurecer sua ideia, para não correr o risco de receber uma enxurrada de votos negativos lá.

Answer (score 4):

Eu gostei da idéia, mas tenho duas observações:

- Acho que é caso de postar no Meta da SE, se é que não propuseram ainda.
- Eu adotaria o formato (Perguntas|Notificações), ficando assim a aba:

```
   ___________________________
 / (2|0) Stack Overflow em ... \_________________________________________
```

> Update: Há uma solução com userscript no **[StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/2362)**.